# Javascript array compare function using filter - not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include

I wrote the following code to answer the question:

Write a function justCoolStuff() that takes in two arrays of strings, and, using the built-in .filter() method, returns an array with the items that are present in both arrays.

I wanted to solve this problem using loops instead of the includes() array method.  Am I on the right track?  Code returns an empty array filled with empty arrays.

```js
const justCoolStuff = (arrOne,arrTwo) => {
  const sharedWord = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arrTwo.length; j++) {
      sharedWord.push(arrOne.filter(arr => arrOne[i] === arrTwo[j]));
    }
  }
  return sharedWord;
};


const coolStuff = ['gameboys', 'skateboards', 'backwards hats', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'pogs', 'my room', 'temporary tattoos'];

const myStuff = [ 'rules', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'wedgies', 'sweaters', 'skateboards', 'family-night', 'my room', 'braces', 'the information superhighway']; 


console.log(justCoolStuff(myStuff, coolStuff))

// Should print [ 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'skateboards', 'my room' ]
```

Also, is there a way to write this correctly using a callback function, making it more understandable/readable?

Comment: `filter` returns an array, you push the result of the filter to an array, hence nested arrays. This filter doesn't even make any sense because you don't use the `arr` variable

Answer (score 1):

You are not on the right track.

```
const justCoolStuff = (arrOne,arrTwo) => {
  //  const sharedWord = []; //you don't need this
  return arrOne.filter(function(item) {
    // you need to return true if item is in arrTwo
    // there are a number of ways in which you could test for this, one being
    // using includes on arrTwo
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The demo below shows how you can use **`Array#filter`**
and `Array#includes` (or `Array#indexOf`):

```js
const 
    coolStuff = ['gameboys', 'skateboards', 'backwards hats', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'pogs', 'my room', 'temporary tattoos'],
    myStuff = [ 'rules', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'wedgies', 'sweaters', 'skateboards', 'family-night', 'my room', 'braces', 'the information superhighway'],
    
    justCoolStuff = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item)); //OR
    //justCoolStuff = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter(item => arr2.indexOf(item) > -1);
    
    console.log( justCoolStuff(coolStuff, myStuff) );
```

Comment: Okay, those solutions make sense, thank you for providing that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without array functions

```js
const justCoolStuff = (arrOne, arrTwo) => {
  const sharedWords = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++) {
    const item = arrOne[i]
    for (j = 0; j < arrTwo.length; j++) {
      const other = arrTwo[j]
      if (item === other) {
        sharedWords.push(item);
        break
      }
    }
  }
  return sharedWords;
};


const coolStuff = ['gameboys', 'skateboards', 'backwards hats', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'pogs', 'my room', 'temporary tattoos'];

const myStuff = ['rules', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'wedgies', 'sweaters', 'skateboards', 'family-night', 'my room', 'braces', 'the information superhighway'];


console.log(justCoolStuff(myStuff, coolStuff))

// Should print [ 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'skateboards', 'my room' ]
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the solution I desired from the get go, thank you for filling in the gaps on my incorrect code.  The solution this way is much more involved that I had previously thought.  Really cool to see it this way though, thanks again.